# Old TV show/cartoon about a prehistoric boy and his pet dinosaur

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, dinosaurs, prehistoric

It was set in the stone age.  The boy was part of a tribe, they had rituals (I remember fire ants being a part of the "becoming a man" ritual.) The boy had a pet dinosaur, I believe it was some type of flying dinosaur, maybe pterodactyl or something similar. The dinosaur was flying with the boy on its back.

I have no idea when the show was made but I watched it on TV around 2005-2010 probably.

If you have any questions I am happy to answer, I've been looking for this show for years, haven't come any closer.

Comment: 2005 ... "old".  *cries*

Comment: Lol, i assumed it was older

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may be thinking of ***[Pitt and Kantrop](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0960552/)*** (2005).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitt_%26_Kantrop):

> *Pitt & Kantrop* is a children's television animated series produced by the European Broadcasting Union (EBU) and Millimages. It was shown on BBC One and CBBC in the United Kingdom and on Clan in Spain. **It follows the journey of a 13-year-old boy named Pitt and his pet pterodactyl Kantrop as they adventure through the wilderness of the Stone Age eras, and solve problems in the tribe's village.** It is from the same creators of *Watch My Chops*.

Comment: Dude that is increasable!!!! This is exactly it!!!! I've been looking for it for the past 5 years!!!! How did you find it???? Did you have the name in your head? Or did you look it up? Because I've been searching, believe me, and nothing came up, even though my description wasn't generic at all, pretty specific actually... Damn your are a legend my friend!!!! Years of search and all i needed to do was post here i guess... Thank you very very very much! Just 1 hour after i posted too, you are quick! My god, thank you so much!

Comment: Incredible*, i was so excited i couldn't spell, lol

Comment: @user2254742 - For me, a Google search using the term "cartoon boy pterodactyl" brings the Wikipedia page for this show up as the first result. Your mileage may vary. As this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Yeah, for me too, it seems like i was search all the wrong combinations i guess...